# Why is Lord Ganesha's birth celebrated on Chaturthi (Tithi) instead of on a star?

Tags: vishnu, tradition, ganesha

There is a system in Hindu tradition that birthday will be celebrated pertaining to the star on that day. Thiruvonam is the star for Lord Vishnu; Moolam for Hanuman;  etc.

Then for Lord Ganesha why his birth is celebrated in Chaturthi (Thithi) not star?

Comment: not only that Ramanavami, nrsima jayanthi and parusarama jayanthiv all other are not star based..its again based on region.. Krishna jayanthi in Tamil Iyengar is sep 10th as rohini falls on astami thiti where as north and smarta tradition its on sravan krishna paksha astami..

Comment: @prasanna- Am expecting right answer. You are particular about region only not relevant answer.

Comment: Srimad Bhagavatam how syamntka uppakyanma gives importance to ganesh chathuthi vratha on bhadrapadd masa chathurthi thiti its when Ganesh is reedeems ones dosha of seeing chandra on chathurthi thiti ..

Comment: As far as I know,  Devi Parvati made a doll of male child and gave life to it.   The birthstar of the occasion might not be known.   Further,  Ganapati Chaturdhi was the occasion for his coronation as Ganadhipati.

Comment: I believe the whole story is symbolic @SrimannarayanaKV its not true story if its true then it leaves pandoro box of question on the capablities of Godly beings the whole story is beyond logic, but if you interupt based thathva then it had god meaning.. like parvathi and shiva akasha abhimani they took prithivi which is tamo abhimani to create Ganesh..decapitation of tamo guna is the key  from the story replace the head with medha sakthi which elephant is know for..

Comment: @PrasannaR: In Hinduism many concepts are symbolic.  If we start digging into many aspects, many puranic stories will turn out to be symbolic only.  As the OP is asking a query based on Puranas, I had restricted my comment to that extent only